# Having trouble looping over a function every time I read in a '\n' from an input file in C

Tags: c, parsing, input, newline

For one of my programming classes we were supposed to write a program that could solve a sudoku puzzle using backtracking. While that was supposed to be the hard part, I'm embarrasingly stuck on parsing input. 
The program is supposed to read in input in the form of:

```
2..5.4.3.1...9...8.........9...5...6.4.6.2.7.7...4...5.........4...8...1.5.2.3.4.
7.....4...2..7..8...3..8.799..5..3...6..2..9...1.97..6...3..9...3..4..6...9..1.35
....7..2.8.......6.1.2.5...9.54....8.........3....85.1...3.2.8.4.......9.7..6....
```

where the program reads in a line, and if it's a valid puzzle it solves it and prints the solution, then continues onto the next line, then the next until it eventually reaches EOF. Right now I have a function that reads in the puzzle using getchar(), and I got the idea from my instrctor to set a global variable that gets turned on when this function reaches EOF. Then in main have a while loop that essentially says

```
While(not done)
{
read puzzle
solve puzzle
}
```

Anyway, here's the actual code, I've only included the two functions that I'm trying to use to read input, I've confirmed everything about the actual sudoku solver works:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define TRUE 1
#define FALSE 0
int done = FALSE;

void readInPuzzle(int puzzle[9][9])
{
    //puzzle [8][9] = '\0';
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    int c;
    for (i = 0; i < 9; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < 9; j++)
        {
            c = getchar();
            if (c != '\n')
            {
                /*This converts the chars from getchar(); into easier to manage ints*/
                if (c == '.') c = 48;
                puzzle[i][j] = (c - '0');
            }
            if (c == EOF) done = TRUE;
        }
    }
}

void main()
{
    int puzzle[9][9];
    while (done == FALSE);
    {
        readInPuzzle(puzzle);
        if (solvePuzzle(puzzle,0,0) == TRUE)
            printPuzzle(puzzle);
    }
}
```

When I run the program and give it the above input, it runs forever which I assume means the 'done' variable never gets set to 1. Am I way off base on how to use global variables? Is there a better way to have this program repeat itself every time it reads in a '\n' from input?

Comment: rather than #define true and false, use: `#include <stdbool.h>`

Comment: the return type from function `main()` is always 'int', not 'void'

Comment: Rather than letting a void function setting a global flag, you could use the function's return value to indicate success or failure.

Comment: Don't edit your question/title, just ["accept"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) one of the answers below.

Comment: can the input lines be less than 81 characters (9x9)?   if each input line is 81characters + the trailing '\n' then the logic for  readInPuzzle() needs some modification

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
while (done == FALSE);
```

Here it stuck in that while statement only.

remove `;`

```
  while (done == FALSE)
  {
    readInPuzzle(puzzle);
    if (solvePuzzle(puzzle,0,0) == TRUE)printPuzzle(puzzle);
  }
```

Comment: Haha, that is embarassing. Thanks though!

Comment: Its programing...and such simple problem sometimes spoil your whole evening at job...!

Answer (score 0):

sample to fix

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define TRUE  1
#define FALSE 0

int readInPuzzle(int puzzle[9][9])
{
  int i, j;
  char c;
  for (i = 0; i < 9; i++)
  {
    for (j = 0; j < 9; j++)
    {
      if(EOF == scanf(" %c", &c))
        return FALSE;
      if (c == '.') c = '0';
      puzzle[i][j] = c - '0';
    }
  }
  return TRUE;
}

int main(void)
{
  int puzzle[9][9];
  while (FALSE != readInPuzzle(puzzle))
  {
    if (solvePuzzle(puzzle,0,0) == TRUE)printPuzzle(puzzle);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code corrects the logic for reading in the puzzle, handles certain input file format errors and corrects the problem with the 'while' statement in main()

Note: the stub functions solvePuzzle() and printPuzzle() are only added to make the posted code cleanly compile

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define TRUE 1
#define FALSE 0
int done = FALSE;

int solvePuzzle(int puzzle[9][9], int row, int col)
{
    puzzle = puzzle;
    row = row;
    col = col;
    return TRUE;
}

void printPuzzle(int puzzle[9][9])
{
    puzzle = puzzle;
}

void readInPuzzle(int puzzle[9][9])
{
    //puzzle [8][9] = '\0';
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    int c;

    for (i = 0; i < 9; i++)
    {

        for (j = 0; j < 9; j++)
        {

            c = getchar();

            if( EOF == c )
            {
                if( i || j)
                { // then input file improperly formatted
                    printf("input file format incorrect, unexpected EOF at row=%d, col=%d\n", i, j );
                }
                done = TRUE;
                return;
            }

            else if( '\n' == c )
            { // then input file improperly formatted
                printf( "input file format incorrect, unexpected newline at row=%d col=%d\n", i, j );
                done = TRUE;
                return;
            }


            /*This converts the chars from getchar() into easier to manage ints*/
            if (c == '.') c = '0';
            puzzle[i][j] = (c - '0');
        } // end for
    } // end for
    getchar();  // read newline (if any)
} // end function: readInPuzzle


int main( void )
{
    int puzzle[9][9];

    while ( !done )
    {
        readInPuzzle(puzzle);
        if( done ) break;

        if (solvePuzzle(puzzle,0,0) )
        {
            printPuzzle(puzzle);
        }
    }
    return 0;
} // end function; main
```